# Should my page check the x509certificate? If so how?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I must admit that I am floundering a bit with certificates. I can't find much that's very clear with web searches. I have a 3rd party posting a file to my web page using an x509certificate.

I was told we have the party's public key. Can I just compare Request.ClientCertificate.PublicKey to this value? Can I encode them as strings and do a string compare?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a comparison? User authentication? authorization? identification?

Comment: That the certificate supplied is 'valid'.

Comment: In this case, the HttpClientCertificate class has a 'IsValid' property. This is different from comparing it to a reference value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PublicKey is an array of bytes. Simply compare the reference with what you got in the request.

Trying to encode as string may get you into trouble with non-printable characters (if a byte is zero, what should the equivalent character be ?)

Comment: I'm just wondering how to store the user supplied key for comparison. I suppose I could store it in a file with a binary reader/write.

Comment: well, you could transform each byte into equivalent hexadecimal value, so a zero byte would be "00". I was more thinking about string encoding, which is not exactly what you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was thinking more of something like Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.PublicKey).